# Как правильно поставить ударение в слове "всенощная"?

Tags: фонетика

Я всегда говорила "всенОщная", но по телевизору услышала: "всЕнощная". А как все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 1):

С ударением-то тут ясно, вс**е**нощная.
А вот насчет сочетания щн - действительно непросто. 
По правилам-то Ш должно быть твердым, как в *помощник*, Аванесов подтверждает.
Но вот у меня все равно полумягкое, мягче чем в п*омощник*, примерно как в *мощный*. Думаю, это не нарушение нормы.

Answer (score 0):

Не всегда стоит руководствоваться своим опытом. Как выясняется, привычная для многих свеклА оказалась свЁклой, тортЫ оказались тОртами и т.п. Поэтому лучше обращаться к  официальным источникам - словарям. Правильно произносить "всЕнощная".

Answer (score 0):

Правильно произносить: *"вс**е**ношная"* (с ударением на Е и звуком Ш на месте Щ).